# Variables change when static before stays the same when not-static

Tags: java, multithreading, object, graphics, static

I have a working class that shows the time on a window, but the only problem is when I make the String variables non-static they don't update at all, but when I make the String variables static they updates themselves. I don't understand why this is happening. The codes are below:

```
public class Test extends Panel implements Runnable {
int second;
int minute;
int hour;
static String second_S = "1";
static String minute_S = "1";
static String hour_S = "1";

static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clock");
static Test panel = new Test(500, 500, 1);

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread time = new Thread(new Test());

    frame.add(panel);
    Frame.showFrame(frame);

    time.start();

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    g.drawString(hour_S, 250, 250);
    g.drawString(minute_S, 280, 250);
    g.drawString(second_S, 310, 250);

}

public Test() {

    second = 0;
    minute = 0;
    hour = 1;

}

public Test(int width, int length, int minusBy) {
    super(width, length, minusBy);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            second++;
            if (second > 60) {
                second = 1;
                minute++;
            }
            if (minute > 60) {
                minute = 1;
                hour++;
            }
            if (hour > 12) {
                hour = 1;
            }

            hour_S = Integer.toString(hour);
            minute_S = Integer.toString(minute);
            second_S = Integer.toString(second);

            System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);
            panel.repaint();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You should not create or access Swing components from any thread other than the EDT. This code is inherently in violation of Swing's threading policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `Test` instances :

```
static Test panel = new Test(500, 500, 1); // one which displays the values of the members

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread time = new Thread(new Test()); // and another which updates the variables

    frame.add(panel);
    Frame.showFrame(frame);

    time.start();

}
```

When your members are static, both instances share the same valus. When your members are not static, the instance that updates the values is not the same instance that displays the values, and each instance has its own members, so the values of the instance variables in the `panel` instance remain unchanged.

If you would use the same instance, your code will work with non staticc members :

```
static Test panel = new Test(500, 500, 1);

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread time = new Thread(panel);

    frame.add(panel);
    Frame.showFrame(frame);

    time.start();

}
```

Comment: Ohhh. I see. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code works, so there is no need to go into that. I will just quickly explain why that happens when you use the keyword "static".

Essentially a when you use a static keyword, it makes the variable or method an instance member of the parent class.

It makes your program memory efficient (i.e it saves memory).

Also, it is initialized when the class itself loads. So in your case, the variables don't initialize in time for it to be declared and implemented. That is why you find it works when you make the variables static.

For more information, [This really does help!](http://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java)

Hope this helps answer your question.